# Arrays in regards to typedef structs

Tags: c, arrays

I have a typedef struct representing a circle with 3 integers; x y and radius
ive been told to create an array of five circles C5, such that circle Ci has x=i,y=i,r=i

How do i store this in the array?

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have.

Comment: Apologies. 

Basically what im trying to ask is if its possible to store pointers in an array, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array like this:

```
type_name circles[5];
```

where "type_name" is the name of your typedef struct. Then you can assign values to the slots in the array like this:

```
// set the circle in slot 2 to have the values of x, y, and r
circles[2].x = x;
circles[2].y = y;
circles[2].r = r;
```

where `x` is of type "type_name".

Comment: Do i create the circles array in the typedef itself, do i define it, or in the main function?

Comment: In the main function. If you put it in the typedef, it would become part of your definition of a circle, whereas what you want is an array of circles.

Comment: `type_name circles[5]` is good, but in `C`, one can't assign a complex type, only primitive types, eg, `circles[2].r = 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @RobStreeting's answer:

If you want an array of pointers to `type_name`, then you would use:

```
type_name* circles[5];
```

Note that this does *not* set aside space for 5 `type_name`s; it only sets aside space for 5 *pointers* to those things.